# Issue while trying to append route parameter in js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

**Below is my js code that is appending the route and its parameter in anchor tag.**

```
var href = "{!! route('ShowUserMainForm', ['RoleID'=>" + row.RoleID + "]) !!}";

var UserColumn = "<td><a href=' " + href + "'><button>Users</button></a></td>";
```

**It gives below url**

http://localhost:1234/public/system-users/%20+%20row.RoleID%20+%20

I am expecting below.

> http://localhost:1234/public/system-users/1

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. of ways to do it:

Because {!! !!} block codes render before JavaScript code so you need to create route and then concat RoleID outside {!! !!} .

if **row.RoleID** is json :

```
var href = "public/system-users/" + row.RoleID
```

or

```
var href = "{!! route('ShowUserMainForm') !!}" + row.RoleID;
```

or

```
var href = "{!! route('ShowUserMainForm', ['RoleID'=>'']) !!}" + row.RoleID;
```

Answer (score 1):

`%20` -> percent encoding for space character

What you're seeing is this string assigned as the value for `RoleID`: `+ row.RoleID +`.

You're running Laravel inside those outside quotes, so just drop JS string concatenation, and write straight PHP (presuming you have a `$row` variable available on the server-side):

```
var href = "{!! route('ShowUserMainForm', ['RoleID'=> $row.RoleID]) !!}";
```

When Laravel is rendering your route into the anchor tag and building up that HTML (everything that happens inside those `{!! !!}`), you're operating on the server. When you are running javascript, you are in the client. You cannot send data from the client to the server in the manner which you are attempting.

Comment: row is JSON object and role.RoleID is its JSON property

Comment: row is a client side JSON variable

Comment: right, that is why you cannot use `row` inside `{!! !!}`, you'd have to use something like `$row` on the server-side. that code has already run _on the server_, presumably a [blade template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade). so by the time you have the javascript object on the _client_ side, it's too late. the request-response lifecycle has terminated. you cannot rerender that route, unless you are doing so separately in the browser (using dom mainpulation, etc.).